# Incorrect City, State, Zipcode Audit

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am currently trying to audit our systems for invalid information. I want to compare companies_address against my xro_zips table that has City, State, Zipcode.
I can return some zip codes that are not matching up between these two tables, but I would also like to return incorrect city names and state abbreviations where the zip codes match between the two tables.

This is what I have so far..

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'workplace_base' as [db_id], c.external_id, c.company, ca.city, 
   ISNULL(ca.[state],'') as [state], ISNULL(ca.zip_code,'') as zip_code, d.division
FROM Workplace_base.dbo.companies_address ca
   INNER JOIN Workplace_base.dbo.companies c ON ca.company_id = c.company_id
   INNER JOIN Workplace_base.dbo.divisions d ON c.owner_division_id = d.division_id
   LEFT JOIN Workplace_base.dbo.xro_zips z ON ca.zip_code = z.ZipCode
      and ca.[state] = z.[State]
WHERE z.ZipCode IS NULL
```

Any help would be great. Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: Do you want separate queries for different mismatches or a single query that returns columns identifying all of the issues with each problem row, e.g. `CityMismatch` (bit)?

Comment: If I could have one query that identifies all issues, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing should give all discrepancies:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT 
    'workplace_base' as [db_id], 
    c.external_id, 
    c.company, 
    ca.city AS City1, 
    z.City AS City2, 
    ISNULL(ca.[state],'') as [State1], 
    ISNULL(z.[State],'') as [State2], 
    ca.zip_code as zip_code1,
    z.ZipCode as zip_code2,
    ISNULL(ca.zip_code,'Missing ZIP') as zip_code_check1, 
    ISNULL(z.ZipCode,'Extra ZIP') as zip_code_check2, 
    d.division,
    CASE WHEN ca.city <> z.city THEN 'City Mismatch' ELSE 'OK' END AS CityCheck,    
    CASE WHEN ca.[state] <> z.[state] THEN 'State Mismatch' ELSE 'OK' END AS StateCheck,    
FROM Workplace_base.dbo.companies_address ca
INNER JOIN Workplace_base.dbo.companies c ON ca.company_id = c.company_id
INNER JOIN Workplace_base.dbo.divisions d ON c.owner_division_id = d.division_id
FULL OUTER JOIN Workplace_base.dbo.xro_zips z ON ca.zip_code = z.ZipCode
) AS Comparison
WHERE zip_code1 IS NULL or zip_code2 IS NULL OR CityCheck <> 'OK' OR StateCheck <> 'OK'
```